# Web scraping with XMLHttpRequest not showing expected data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get data from https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=ETIT.tg by using javascript code and push the result as html table in .
Below is what i try

```
function GetData()  {
            var XMLReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
          
            XMLReq.open("POST", "/api/general/GetHistos");
            XMLReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            XMLReq.send(JSON.stringify({
                ticker: "ETIT.tg",
                datedeb: "2022-07-20",
                datefin: "2022-08-17",
                xperiod: "0"
            }))          
            XMLReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(XMLReq.readyState == 4 && XMLReq.status == 200) {
                alert(XMLReq.responseText);
              }
            }
          
            XMLReq.send();
          }
```

I also try promise after inspecting the site web.
the code is the following :

```
const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "accept": "*/*",
          "accept-language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
          "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"104\"",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Android\"",
          "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
          "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
          "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
        },
        "referrer": "https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BRVMAG",
        "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        "body": "{\"ticker\":\"BRVMAG\",\"datedeb\":\"2022-06-19\",\"datefin\":\"2022-08-16\",\"xperiod\":\"0\"}",
        "method": "POST",
        "mode": "no-cors",
        "credentials": "include"
      };
      
      fetch('https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

as result [image: i get this].
Please can some one help me to figure it?

Comment: But I see error code 415 for your request - this is problem I think

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to get the data. But how to create a table   so that i can add all the content (data fetched) inside?

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
    "body": "{\"ticker\":\"BRVMAG\",\"datedeb\":\"2022-05-23\",\"datefin\":\"2022-08-18\",\"xperiod\":\"0\"}"
  };
  
  fetch('https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[image: The json result is in array]